# Get values from DataTable with .Select c#

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, datatables

I am trying to do a Select in a datatable to get the next red values:

[image]

My code is this:

```
string lvfin = Convert.ToString(DataTable.Rows[j][DataTable.Columns.Count - 1]);
DataRow[] results = DataTable.Select("Nivel = '" + lvfin + "'");
foreach (DataRow dr in results)
{
  list.Add(DataTable.Rows.IndexOf(dr));
}
```

This code is inside 2 loops with J and I as indexes to go over the Datable. But with this Select I get all values in Level 2, so I am having the values in red and the values in blue. How can I get only the red values?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter also for Nivel 1 (for the red values, it is COSC-1218-SIT41SCH)

Comment: But If I don't know what there is in that cell? that solution is just valid for COSC...

Comment: So you want to retrieve a set of data without knowing the criteria?